# Is there a way to create WiFi with one Access Point, which should cover a big building?

Tags: wifi, lora, lorawan, wifi-halow

I need to create a WiFi network(or other types e.g. LoRa) for IoT devices, inside a building. The Building has three floors, each about 250 square meters.

The main constraint is that I can't use any cables, I can use only one AP. I read about WiFi 900MHz (802.11ah) which look like a perfect solution but I can't find any device in such standard. I add that I want to connect about 30 IoT devices and I want to send about 100 kbps from each device to the AP.

Is it possible to make such network using WiFi 802.11b using the most powerful router (in case of signal strength) with an outdoor antenna with e.g. 10dB?

I'm afraid that LoRa's bandwidth will be the bottleneck. I'm looking for some other ideas.

Comment: You say that LoRa's bandwith might be the bottleneck. But what bandwith do you actually require?

Comment: @Paul about 100 kbps from each device to the AP

Comment: You could probably do something like use multiple APs linked wirelessly.  It's essentially unavoidable that you'll need multiple mains powered boxes to do this, since battery powered nodes can't be awake often enough to repeat each other's traffic.

Comment: NB-IoT has a better bandwidth.

Answer (score 5):

One Access Point for 250m2 and 3 floors, seems to stretch WiFi a bit.

It depends on the material in the building, surrounding interference and antenna.

To give a answer, one should do a survey and measurements on site.

A Guesstimate would be probably not.

Comment: Do you know any other technologies which could help to solve the problem?

Comment: ANT (nrf24) in a mesh configuration or WiFi with BatMan (Mesh) and perhaps Bluetooth 4.2 if I remember correct, that has improved the reach.

Comment: Do you know how nrf24 is related to esp8266 mesh?

Comment: nrf24 is the ANT protocoll, ESP8266 is WiFi (802.11). But you don't give credits?

Comment: ANT, see https://www.thisisant.com/developer/ant/ant-basics and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANT_(network)

Comment: ANT is not wifi, and I would not recommend using it for such. You would probably be better off loading the BLE softdevice into an nRF52/51/24 and trying to run ethernet over that. And even that I don't recommend

Comment: @cujo Please read the conversation, and look for "other technologies".

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with adding a wireless bridge to your network for signal amplification? No wires needed and you get the added range.